# How to change cursor style in android?

Tags: android-emulator

I have different views on my activity. I wanna change my cursor style when cursor is move to any view. How to do same in android.For example there is a normal cursor on the android activity when cursor moves to a button i wanna change cursor style normal to finger style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cursor I know about in Android is [used alongside SQLite databases.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) Seeing as Android phones/tablets are all touchscreen... there is no 'mouse' cursor, except in the emulator.

Of course, you could draw a cursor that followed finger movement, but I can't think of a lot of reasons you'd want do that in a standard UI.

Comment: It's not true that Andorid does not have mouse cursor/pointer. You can plug mouse to most of the Andorid device via USB interface.

Comment: To be fair, I posted this before Android 3.0 existed. What devices work with usb mice on 2.3 and below?

Answer (score 1):

actually there is a mouse cursor in Android 3.0 and later. The only way to see it is to connect a bluetooth mouse to the device and youll see the cursor once you move the mouse around. The only reason I found this site was because I wanted to change the cursor color so sorry I cant help you with that one.

Comment: Thanks for reply.No issue, will find.